# Function as Child is really an anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs

I've reading that Function as Child is an anti-pattern. A lot of React developers agree with this. But recently React Team released a new Context API that uses that practice.

After all, isn't it an anti-pattern?

Comment: Render prop is cleaner way to achieve this. If React team uses something doesn't automatically mean this is the best approach. Context API design itself has questions, so..

Comment: can you please point to some reading where this pattern is being called an anti pattern?

Comment: You're right. But I believe that React Team knows React like nobody else. They have reasons to choose FaC instead of Render Props. For example, Render Props doesn't work well with `React.PureComponent`.

Comment: Many discussions in forums cite this article: [Function as Child Components Are an Anti-Pattern](https://americanexpress.io/faccs-are-an-antipattern/)